# Showing dynamic rates for all dates using jquery ui calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, date-range

In a Car Rental Website Reservation System, i am using jquery ui calendar as a date range picker for "From Date" and "To Date" selection.

I want to show dynamic rates for different dates as shown in figure.  Please let me know how i can do that ?

```
<input type="text" id="booking-from" name="booking-from" />
<input type="text" id="booking-to" name="booking-to" />

$( "#booking-from" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    minDate: 0,
    firstDay: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {

        /*var day1 = $("#booking-from").datepicker('getDate').getDate() + 1;                 
        var month1 = $("#booking-from").datepicker('getDate').getMonth();             
        var year1 = $("#booking-from").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
        year1 = year1.toString().substr(2,2);
        var fullDate = day1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + year1;*/         
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1));
        $( "#booking-to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", newMin );
    }
});
$( "#booking-to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    minDate: '+2d',
    changeMonth: true,
    firstDay: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var newMax  = new Date(maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1));
        $( "#booking-from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate",  newMax);
    }
});

$("#booking-from").datepicker('setDate', '+1');
$("#booking-to").datepicker('setDate', '+8');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/h3wGx/4/)

[image: dynamic rates for different dates]

Comment: COuld you add the code that you already have/tried so a person in the know can jump in and suggest a solution?

Comment: @Dilettant  Current jsFiddle link added

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display additional text alongside dates in jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765931/display-additional-text-alongside-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage it using  [jQuery Datepicker by Keith Wood](http://plugins.jquery.com/kbw.datepick/) library

```
$('#startPicker,#endPicker').datepick({
                onSelect: customRange, onDate: showDayOfYear, showTrigger: '#calImg'
        });

function customRange(dates) {
        if (this.id === 'startPicker') {
            console.log(dates[0]);
            $('#endPicker').datepick('option', 'minDate', dates[0] || null);
        }
        else {
            $('#startPicker').datepick('option', 'maxDate', dates[0] || null);
        }
 }

 function pad(n) {
        return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n
  }

var specificPrices = {"2016-06-12": "$300", "2016-06-26": "$63", "2016-07-26": "$63", "2016-07-15": "$63", "2016-08-16": "$63"}

function showDayOfYear(date) {
            var checkDate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(date.getDate()); //2015-12-04
            var specificPrice;
            if (specificPrices[checkDate]) {
                specificPrice = specificPrices[checkDate];
            } else {
                specificPrice = '';
            }
            return {
                content: date.getDate() + '<br><sub>' + specificPrice + '</sub>', dateClass: 'showDoY'
}
```

HTML

```
<p><span class="demoLabel">Date range with separate fields:</span></p>
<input type="text" id="startPicker"> to
<input type="text" id="endPicker">
```

[jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/719oos0s/2/)